# Change page margin inside own environment

Tags: environments, margins

I would like to define an environment, that inserts a page with different margins than defined in the preamble.

I tried using the following LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
  \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,top=20cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot}
  \blindtext[2]
}{
  \newpage

  \restoregeometry
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\end{myenv}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately on the second page there is an unexpected page break after a few lines. The following code produces the desired result.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newenvironment{myenv}{
  \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,top=20cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot}
  \blindtext[2]
}{
  \newpage
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\end{myenv}
\restoregeometry
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

However I do not want to write `\restoregeometry` manually each time I use `myenv`. Can anyone explain me the difference between the two code pieces above and provide a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but the command `\AfterEndEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package can help you in this.

It inserts some code just after the environment is ended.

So, adding to your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{myenv}{\restoregeometry}
```

should permit you to achieve what you want.

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=5.2cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndEnvironment{myenv}{\restoregeometry}

\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,top=20cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot}%
  \blindtext[2]%
}{%
  \newpage%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}

\end{myenv}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

To answer the question in your comment, I think that `\restoregeometry` doesn't work if you put it at the environment end, because the latter forms a group.

In fact, if you tell LaTeX to execute `\restoregeometry` after the group is finished with the command `\aftergroup`, you have a solution that hasn't the need for `\AfterEndEnvironment`:

```
\newenvironment{myenv}{%
  \newgeometry{left=1.5cm,top=20cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,nohead,nofoot}%
  \blindtext[2]%
}{%
  \newpage\aftergroup\restoregeometry%
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems to do the trick. But I still do not understand why there is a difference at all.

Comment: @user26756 See the edited answer. BTW: remember that you can accept answers by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)).